# Can we use scanf("%[^\n]s,str) if we have to take multiple strings consisting of space as input?

Tags: c, string

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",str1);
scanf("%[^\n]s",str2);
```

Its not working when I used it for multiple arrays.
Is there any mistake from my side or we cant use it for multiple arrays?

Comment: `%[^\n]s` is wrong anyways, use *either* `[]` *or* `s`. `%[]` does not skip initial whitespace, one of the many pitfalls of `scanf()`. See my [beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]",str1);
scanf(" %[^\n]",str2);
```

Note the space in front, that forces `scanf()` to skip leading whitespace (and the newline that's not read by the first call counts as a whitespace character).

**But:** This code has possible *undefined behavior*, it causes buffer overflow if the input has a line longer than your `str1` or `str2` can store. **You should never write such code**.

With `scanf()`, you can use a *field width* to limit the amount of characters read:

```
str1[256];
scanf(" %255[^\n]", str1); // one less because a 0 character must be appended
```

Much better is to use the function dedicated to the job of reading a *line*: `fgets()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>      // for fgets()
#include <string.h>     // for strcspn()
#define BUFFERSIZE 256

// [...]
str1[BUFFERSIZE];

int main(void)
{
    // [...]
    // no need to subtract 1 here, `fgets()` accounts for the trailing `0`:
    if (!fgets(str1, BUFFERSIZE, stdin))
    {
        // read error, e.g. print error message
        exit(1);
    }

    // fgets includes the newline if there was one, so strip it:
    str1[strcspn(str1, "\n")] = 0;

    // [...]
}
```

Comment: But your suggested `scanf()` format produces a different result than the OP's does for the first line if that line begins with whitespace.  It also produces a different result than the OP probably expects for the second line if that line begins with whitespace.

Comment: It's just there for completeness, I would never suggest `scanf()` for this task *at all*.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `scanf()` as you describe ...

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",str1);
```

Reads characters from the standard input into the character array designated by `str1`, *not* skipping leading whitespace, up to but not including the first newline.  **The newline, if any, remains unread.**  A matching failure occurs (and therefore you cannot rely on a string terminator being written) if that results in zero characters being transferred to the array.  Otherwise, `scanf()` then attempts to read (and ignore) an `'s'` character, but that must always produce a matching failure; no character will be consumed.

The function will return 0 in the event that the inevitable matching failure occurs attempting to match the `%[` directive, or 1 in the event that it occurs attempting to match the 's'.  It will return `EOF` if called when zero characters remain to be read from the standard input, or if an I/O error occurs.

If you immediately follow by attempting to read again with the same format, then the second read must always have either an input failure or a matching failure in the `%[` directive, because if any more characters are available, the next one must be a newline.

---

Usually, reading line by line is better accomplished via `fgets()`.  If you must do it via `scanf()` then you should do something along these lines:

```
char str1[100];
char c;
int result;

// Note use of a field width to protect from buffer overrun:
result = scanf("%99[^\n]%c", str1, &c);
switch (result) {
    case EOF: /* no characters available or I/O error */
        /* ... handle error ... */
        break;
    case 0:
        /* the first character was a newline */
        result = getchar();  // consume the newline
        assert(result == '\n');
        str1[0] = '\0';      // ensure the (empty) string is terminated
        break;
    case 1:
        /* should happen only at end of file or on I/O error */
        assert(feof(stdin) || ferror(stdin));
        /* ... any special handling for this being the last line of the file ... */
        break;
    case 2:
        if (c != `\n`) {
            /* the line was longer than 99 characters (excluding the newline) */
            /* ... recover from overlength line ... */
        }
        break;
    default:
        /* should never happen */
        /* ... handle unexpected result ... */
}
```

That's pretty lengthy even without some of the details filled in, so I'd advise you to factor it out into its own function.  Note, too, that `fgets()` makes it simpl*er*, but it still has its complications.  In particular, you still need to watch out for overlength lines, and `fgets()` includes the trailing newline in the string (when there is one).